# Validating all data with DB before bulk insert mongoose/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am trying to validate the array of objects before inserting them into the mongodb.

what i am trying to do is, lets say i have an object like below

```
    var data= { prodDetails: 
       [ 
         { measured: 'Liters',
           name: 'A',
           prodCode: '713',
           status: true },
         { measured: 'Liters',
           name: 'B',
           prodCode: '713',
           status: true },
         { measured: 'Liters',
           name: 'C',
           prodCode: '674',
           status: true } 
]
};
```

before making a bulk insert call i want check whether the given `prodCode` is valid DB Code or not and `name` duplicated or not

i am using `node` `bluebird` promises.

i tried the following code to validate `prodCode`

```
var bulkOperations = {
    bulkProdInsert: function (body) {
        return new Promise(function (reslv, rej) {
            if (body.prodDetails.length > 0) {
                common_lg.getValueById(body, "typesProd", body.prodDetails[0].prodCode).then(bulkOperations.successCallback(reslv, rej, body)).catch(bulkOperations.errCallback(reslv, rej, body));
            };
            reslv();
        });
    },

    successCallback: function (reslv, rej, body) {
        return function (res) {
            if (res) {
                body.prodDetails.splice(0, 1);
                if (body.prodDetails.length > 0) {
                    common_lg.getValueById(body, "typesProd", body.prodDetails[0].prodCode).then(bulkOperations.successCallback(reslv, rej, body)).catch(bulkOperations.errCallback(reslv, rej, body));
                }
            };
        };
    },

    errCallback: function (reslv, rej, body) {
        return function (err) {
            body.prodDetails.splice(0, 1);
            if (body.prodDetails.length > 0) {
                common_lg.getValueById(body, "typesProd", body.prodDetails[0].prodCode).then(bulkOperations.successCallback(reslv, rej, body)).catch(bulkOperations.errCallback(reslv, rej, body));
            };
        };
    }
};
```

but i want to do is insert all the objects/documents into DB when `name` and `prodCode` of all the objects/documents is validated.

how to achieve this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check the input object and then make DB calls. I would suggest the `.map` [method of bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).

```
var promise = require('bluebird');
var checkValues = promise.method( function(prod){
  if( isValid(prod.prodCode) ){
    return prod;
  }
  //something went wrong!
  throw new Error('prodCode ' + prod.prodCode + ' is invalid');
}
promise.map( data.prodDetails, checkValues )
.then(function(){
  //it worked! You can call the DB now.
})
.catch(function(error){
  //something went wrong, look at that error (or pass along)
})
```

So long as your `checkValues` method is a promise, you can run it against every value in your input array, and use the success of `.then` to know things worked and call your DB!